# Отключение появления экранной клавиатуры на планшетах

Tags: android, ios, vue.js, ace

Есть веб приложение на Vue.js, требуется отключить всплывание экранной клавиатуры на планшетах под управлением ios\android\windows(не обязательно) при клике на input'ы и textarea. А то даже при вызове элементарного select с выбором локализации вываливается эта клавиатура.

Причем обычным editable:false реализовать не выйдет. Т.к набор текста будет осуществляться кнопками, под редактором. Да и думаю с простыми селектами и чекбоксами тогда будут проблемы.

Задача осложняется тем что помимо обычного textarea в приложении используется текстовый редактор Ace.

Может кто сталкивался с подобным. По мере разбирательства во всем этом буду писать сюда дополнительную информацию)